# Hadoop s3: ls: / doesn't exist

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have everything configured in `hdfs-site.xml` and `core-site.xml` and I keep getting the below. Not sure what I am missing:

```
# [Mon Jan 18 11:39:19 root@~]# hadoop fs -ls s3://<bucket_name>/

ls: / doesn't exist
```

Comment: could you paste your config?

Comment: maybe try to follow the path after the url?

Comment: Came across the same error. Did you figure it out? Please do share the solution if you did :)